# how to show selected filter slicer in a card in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a code below and I would like to see the selected hierarchy in a card. how to get around with this ? Many thanks in advance.

Expected Answer:

FY23: Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4

FY24: Q1

```
Selected FY = 
IF( 
    ISFILTERED( 'Calendar'[Fiscal Year] ), 
        CONCATENATEX(  DISTINCT( 'Calendar'[Fiscal Year] )
                                 ,'Calendar'[Fiscal Year] 
                                 ,", " 
), "No filter selected"
)
```

[image: how does it look like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a variation on the following:

```
Selected Periods All = 
VAR t = 
CALCULATE(
    CONCATENATEX(
            VALUES('Calendar'[Fiscal Year]), 
            'Date'[Fiscal Year] & ": " &
                CALCULATE(CONCATENATEX(VALUES('Calendar'[Fiscal Quarter]), 'Calendar'[Fiscal Quarter], ", ")), 
            UNICHAR(10)
        )
)
RETURN   t
```